# No errors, but fwrite() won't write to file

Tags: php, webstorm, fwrite

I've been following PHP and MySQL Web Development 5th edition, but I'm stuck on Chapter 2 because I cannot write to a file.

Here's the code:

```
// open file for appending
$fp = fopen('orders.txt', 'ab', true);

if (!$fp) {
    echo "<p><strong> Your order could not be processed at this time.
            Please try again later.</strong></p>";
    exit;
}

flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
$bytes = fwrite($fp, $outputstring, strlen($outputstring));
echo $bytes;
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
fclose($fp);
```

The echo gives me 65, which seems right, but orders.txt is always completely blank. Could someone give me some advice? I'm using Webstorm with a server hosted on GoDaddy if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant
`$fp = fopen('orders.txt', 'a', true);`
instead of
`$fp = fopen('orders.txt', 'ab', true);`

Note that you can also use the 'w' mode instead of 'a' if you would like to overwrite the file instead of appending at the end of it.